# Append does not read line by line

Tags: python, django, append

this is my codes:

```
self.task_xml = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <django-objects version="1.0">
<object model="task.task" pk="31">
<field name="name" type="CharField">New Task</field>
<field name="parent_task_id" type="IntegerField">0</field>
</object>
<object model="task.task" pk="32">
<field name="name" type="CharField">New Task</field>
<field name="parent_task_id" type="IntegerField">0</field>
</object>
<object model="task.task" pk="33">
<field name="name" type="CharField">New Task</field>
<field name="parent_task_id" type="IntegerField">31</field>
</object>
<object model="task.task" pk="34">
<field name="name" type="CharField">New Task</field>
<field name="parent_task_id" type="IntegerField">31</field>
</object>
</django-objects>"

 58         self.xmlData = ET.fromstring(self.task_xml)
 59 
 60         self.task_list = []
 61         taskList = []                                                           
 62         for obj in self.xmlData.iter("object"):
 63             parent_task_id = obj.find("field[@name='parent_task_id']").text
 64             if parent_task_id == EMPTY_UUID:
 65                 task = TaskViewModel()
 66                 task.id = obj.get("pk")
 67                 task.name =  obj.find("field[@name='name']").text
 68                 task.parent_task_id =  parent_task_id 
 69                 taskList.append(task)
 70         # Apprend taskList:
 71         for task in taskList:
 72             taskViewModel = TaskViewModel(task.id, True)
 73             self.task_list.append(taskViewModel)
```

I think I have a problem in line 65-69 because in my taskList, it only append the last value of id, name,and parent_task_id 4 times. It does not append line by line. Can you please check it.

Comment: Some confusion in your code, u are declaring `self.task_xml` but parse xml from `self.db.task_xml`. Both are same or different ?

Comment: Oh... they are just the same

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your problem but, I am not able to reproduce.

Please check my code below.

```
from lxml import etree as ET
task_xml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <django-objects version="1.0">
<object model="task.task" pk="31">
<field name="name" type="CharField">New Task</field>
<field name="parent_task_id" type="IntegerField">0</field>
</object>
<object model="task.task" pk="32">
<field name="name" type="CharField">New Task</field>
<field name="parent_task_id" type="IntegerField">0</field>
</object>
<object model="task.task" pk="33">
<field name="name" type="CharField">New Task</field>
<field name="parent_task_id" type="IntegerField">31</field>
</object>
<object model="task.task" pk="34">
<field name="name" type="CharField">New Task</field>
<field name="parent_task_id" type="IntegerField">31</field>
</object>
</django-objects>"""

xmlData = ET.fromstring(task_xml)
taskList = []

for obj in xmlData.iter("object"):
    parent_task_id = obj.find("field[@name='parent_task_id']").text
    taskList.append(parent_task_id)

print taskList
```

Output:

```
$ python /tmp/test.py
['0', '0', '31', '31']
```

Will you please correct my code so I can reproduce your problem

**Note: This is not answer, but I cant give this much code in comment**

Comment: Yes this is right... and my problem is.... when I do taskList.append(parent_task_id), it would give the same value 4 times